# The polynomial ideal associated to a prime ideal is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Let $A$ be a ring, $I \subset A$ a prime ideal and $\Phi : A \rightarrow A[x]$ the canonical inclusion homomorphism. Is $I[x]= \{ \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k : n\in \Bbb{N}, (a_k)_{k=0}^n \in I^n \}$ also prime in $A[x]$ ?

I am wondering this in order to apply it on other proof. I have search on my algebra books and notes and it does not appear theory about it. I have tried some ways to prove it, thinking about properties like $A/I$ being a integral domain since $I$ is prime, the relation between prime ideals and nilpotent elements among other things.

Any possible help or reference to already existing theory would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume, from your comment about integral domains, that you are considering commutative rings.

Consider the reduction map $A[x]\to (A/I)[x]$ given by
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i \longmapsto \sum_{i=0}^n(a_i+I)x^i.$$
This is a morphism, induced by the canonical projection $A\mapsto A/I$ and mapping $x$ to $x$, using the universal property of the polynomial ring.

The kernel is precisely $I[x]$. So by the Isomorphism Theorems, $A[x]/I[x]\cong (A/I)[x]$.

If $A$ is commutative with unity and $I$ is prime, then $A/I$ is an integral domain, hence $(A/I)[x]$ is an integral domain, proving that $I[x]$ is a prime ideal of $A[x]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is.

In fact $A[X]/I[X] \cong A/I[X] $, which is an integral domain (because so it is $A/I$) if $I$ is a prime ideal in $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!